# How do you find the source location for an instance variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know that to find the source location for a method, you can do something like:

`Task.method(:completed).source_location`

How would I do something similarly to find the source location for an instance variable (e.g. "@task")?

For example, I'm looking for something like:

```
instance_variable(@task).source_location
```

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Grep or ack :-) Unless it's dynamic, then it's even less trackable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instance variables aren't defined like methods, so there is no location for their definition. They magically spring into existence the first time they are assigned, so, really, they have a location in *time* but not in the *source*.

Comment: Also, YARV will allocate indexed slots for up to 4 instance variables directly in the object header, so in some sense, those instance variables don't exist *at all*.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you for your handy tip Jorg :)